# Release Build of my Android App shows multiple launchers

Tags: android

So I developed an app and was having it go nice and smooth when building it for release. No problems with the signing process or the publishing process, everything seemed to go well.

However, when I install it now instead of showing one launcher for the app it shows multiple. About one for each activity that exists within, it didn't seem to be doing this in earlier release builds and I am not sure why it is doing so now.

If it helps to know;
I have the build variant set to release,
I generate the signed APK with no errors or oddities,
It is signed with both the V1 & V2 and has been since the first release.

Here's my app gradle;

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.atchaca.proverbialwisdom"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionName '1.1.3'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        versionCode 9
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.billingclient:billing:dp-1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}






apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And my manifest;

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    package="com.atchaca.proverbialwisdom">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/proverbial_wisdom_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/proverbial_wisdom_logo_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/FullyTheme">

        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SnippetActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".AboutActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".FavouritesActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".TransactionsActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".FeedbackActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".DeveloperActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your manifest file, all of your activities are set to be the launcher activities. Choose one activity to be your launcher activity and remove the intent filters for the other two activities. So if you wanted the SplashActivity to be the launcher activity, change your manifest to this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

package="com.atchaca.proverbialwisdom">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/proverbial_wisdom_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/proverbial_wisdom_logo_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/FullyTheme">

    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name=".MainActivity">
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name=".SnippetActivity">
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name=".AboutActivity">
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name=".FavouritesActivity">
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name=".TransactionsActivity">
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name=".FeedbackActivity">
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name=".DeveloperActivity">
    </activity>

</application>
```

Hope this helps!